# How to categorize data in a ORACLE table based on a primary key?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table  TRAVEL with column TRIP_ID as primary key.

**SOURCE DATA**

```
TRIP_ID PERSON_NAME DESTINATION SOURCE  TRANSACTION_ID  TRIP_COUNT
100        Mike       London    Zurich      1000B112       1
101        Mike       Paris     Capetown    1000B112       1
102        Mike       Moscow    Madrid      1000B112       1
103        John       Delhi     Moscow      1100A110       1
104        John       Toronto   Zurich      1100A110       1
105        Mary       Chennai   Madrid      1100A111       1
106        Mary       Berlin     Zurich     1100A111       1
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS:**
when I do select * from TRAVEL where TRANSACTION_ID = 1100A111 it returns  below two rows as below .
so I want my data to be categorized based on the transaction_ID on a run time.I dont want to hardcode the value for transaction-ID each time as above but i want to group it in such a way that it should fetch me the above expected results.I mean it should return all the data which are corresponding to the TransactionID in the table and it should not sum up the TRIP COUNT.It should return me the rows as below in my table.I am ok to create view .Please suggest

```
TRIP_ID PERSON_NAME DESTINATION SOURCE  TRANSACTION_ID  TRIP_COUNT

105     Mary           Chennai    Madrid      1100A111        1
106     Mary           Berlin     Zurich      1100A111        1
```

Can someone suggest a query in ORACLE to handle this ? I donot want to hardcode transaction ID

Regards
Sameer

Comment: First you said _"when I do select * from TRAVEL where TRANSACTION_ID = 1100A111 it returns below two rows as below"_, then you said _"It should return me the rows as below"_.  So it looks like your simple SELECT with WHERE gives you what you want.  So what's the problem?  Just looking for a way to not hard-code the value of the WHERE?

Comment: @EdStevens Yes I want to not hardcode as I need to display it in report so I cannot use where clause condition each time ..So please suggest how can i achieve it.It will be really helpful

Comment: How do you know which transaction ID to look for? Is that being passed in by whatever is displaying the report? Or do you want to look for a trip ID (as that is the PK) and find all rows with the same transaction ID; but then again how do you know which trip ID to look for? Or do you want that but picking the highest trip ID; or a name; or something else?